How can I detect Rectangles in PDF using C# iTextSharp
This is the exact same question as this one that no one answered properly:
How can I detect Rectangles and Boxes in PDF using C# iTextSharp
Does anyone have a good answer for this?
Thanks!
I tried the same code from the noted previously asked question, and got the same incorrect results: a null array
